# OpenGL ES 1.1 on the raspberry pi

Tags: c, opengl-es-1.1

I'm trying to get started with OpenGL ES 1.1 on the raspberry.
As X is not accelerated on the raspberry I thought this could be a good (and fast) alternative.
Now what I'm trying to do is mostly UI stuff like menus and so on, nothing like crazy 3D gaming with extra terrestrial effects and shaders! That's why I've chosen OpenGL ES 1.1 instead of the 2.0.

Now I have taken a look at the hello_triangle.c code on the raspberry and have understood a little how it works and how you draw and move/rotate stuff.

Now the problem is that when rotating and moving stuff, the whole model is affected!
What I want to do is have multiple independent objects (like rectangles representing menu items for example) and move them independently, so I could for example rotate the current selected menu entry rectangle.

Thank you!

PS.: [Here's a link to the hello_triangle code I've been studying](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_triangle/triangle.c)